# Python to .bat conversion

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I would like a user on Windows to be able to run my Python program, so I want to convert it to a `.bat` file. Is there a way to convert it? I've tried searching, but didn't find anything.

Comment: I would assume it is as easy as having the user install python (binaries are probably available), and then putting an instruction in a `.bat` file to have python run the program...

Comment: Do you want a batch file that runs a Python script, or do you actually want to translate your script into a batch file?

Comment: @mgilson That's how I read it..., but I have a strange feeling this is heading towards `py2exe`...

Comment: @Mr.Squig Either will do. I just want the effect of the Python script to somehow take place.

Comment: Or then it's just `@python path\to\script.py`, save and exectute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your script is trivial it will not be possible to 'translate' it into a batch file. However two options exist:

- Create a batch file to run the python script
- Attempt to compile the script into an executable

The first option is trivial. Simply create a batch file as so:

```
@ECHO OFF
PATH_TO_PYTHON\python.exe PATH_TO_SCRIPT.py
```

If you are in a corporate environment you could put a python installation on a network and create a batch file to run the script from there. Otherwise you will need the user to install python. If python is on their path then the batch file can be simplified to:

```
@ECHO OFF
python PATH_TO_SCRIPT.py
```

Alternatively, there are options available that attempt to compile scripts into .exe files. I've never had any success with them, but [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) seems the most common.

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can reasonably expect to do this.

Batch files are executed by the Windows command interpreter, which is way way more primitive.

Python is a full-blown programming language with a rich and powerful library of standard modules for all sorts of tasks. All the Windows command interpreter can do is act like a broken shell.

On the other hand, Python is available on Windows, so just tell the user to install it and run your program directly.

Comment: Ummm, how dare you `bash` `cmd.exe` - it's terrific *cough* ;)

Comment: @JJBeck Unless your Python script is **remarkably** simple - then yes, you'll have to install Python, or use `py2exe` or similar

Comment: I would do `p2exe` and a scheduled task to run the `exe`

Comment: @unwind: Excuse me, but I disagree. Batch files can manage [Arrays, structures and linked-lists](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3244) or [Macros with parameters](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2704), for example...

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for my English Im from armenia)
After 10 years I finaly did that without py2exe and some other things

I used openai playground to do that and thats worked:

I just writed "convert python code into .bat file: [my code]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 ways :

1. create a normal text file with an extension .bat and write

```
@ECHO OFF

"python.exe location" "your file.py location"
```

2. create a normal text file with an extension .bat and write

```
"python.exe location" "your file.py location"
pause
```

Answer (score -3):

Just create a batch file that contains this two lines:

```
yourfilename.py
pause
```

Then run the batch file by double-clicking it.